# Reduce JavaScript if statement

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I need help, I have this function in javascript:

```
function getPosition(elementToFind, array) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    if (array == elementToFind) {
      return i;
    }
  }
}
```

And then I have a cycle if that I would like to reduce:

```
if (
  getPosition(1, arraySomething) == 0 &&
  getPosition(2, arraySomething) == 1 &&
  getPosition(3, arraySomething) == 2 &&
  getPosition(4, arraySomething) == 3 &&
  getPosition(5, arraySomething) == 4 &&
  getPosition(6, arraySomething) == 5 &&
  getPosition(7, arraySomething) == 6 &&
  getPosition(8, arraySomething) == 7 &&
  getPosition(9, arraySomething) == 8 &&
  getPosition(10, arraySomething) == 9 &&
  getPosition(11, arraySomething) == 10
) {
  ...code
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Your `getPosition()` function makes no sense to me.  You're looping and comparing `array == elementToFind`, but nothing in that comparison varies as you loop, so it will either always be true or always be false.  The loop does not do anything useful.  If you mean to be compariing `array[i] == elementToFind`, then you might as well just use the Array function `.indexOf()` which is built in and get rid of `getPosition()` entirely.

Comment: As always, if you describe what problem you're really trying to solve (what data you start with and what you're trying to do with it), we can likely help you find a good solution, but here you're asking how to optimize a flawed function without explaining the objective - not much we can do there.

Comment: My objective is to build a image puzzle (25 images(not 11 like up there)), using arrays... What I wanted was when the image 25(painted white) was on the position 24 (the last), the background of the image 25 changed... the cycle if was my attempt to organize the puzzle in order from the image 1 to the image 25, when the puzzle was in that order the background of the image 25 changed. Actually is (array === elementToFind) and not (array == elementToFind)... I apologize, but that is my first year in HTML (I'm 18) and sorry for my bad english :P Thanks apaul34208, no longer need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this

```
var isTrue = true;
for(var n = 1; n <=  length; n ++){
    if (getPosition(n, arraySomething) !== (n - 1)){
        isTrue = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (isTrue){
    ...
}else{
    ...
}
```

?

Comment: Thanks for the help! =)